# Path to web development

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I learn web programming from start to mastery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930331/where-can-i-learn-web-programming-from-start-to-mastery)

I want to be able to make websites like facebook, youtube and google (and even stack overflow!), can someone suggest a step by step guide (as best as you can, if even for part of the way) and not just "Do tutorials and make websites".

I can't go to a we design company and tell them "I'll learn while making sites", or make a website for a client and it ends up being full of holes and security issues.

I'm interested in PHP as opposed to other types, but i'm open minded.

Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow is Written in ASP, BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone here offering a "step by step guide" is essentially the same as offering a tutorial, but with way more work involved.

The reason everyone on here says "here's a starting guide, go try it" is that that's how most of us learned, especially php.

So, this is exactly the answer you asked to not receive, but the absolute best method for learning is to have a goal in mind, and then build it.

Can you comment on this answer with a small project in mind? I'd be more than happy (or maybe other people too) to help get you started. But, I cannot tell you how to rewrite StackOverflow. I doubt the answer would fit in this text box.

Come back with "I want to rewrite Digg" or "I want to share recipes with friends" or something like that, and we can help you.

---

Edits based on comments below.

If you want to make a site like Craigslist, let's focus on one area for now.

Plan it out. What does your final product look like? Remember, you don't want replication of data, so think about what groupings of data you'll need. Things like categories, users, and posts, if we're keeping it simple.

You'll need to create a CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) for each data group. This is a place to create categories, users, posts, view them, edit them as needed, and remove them.

You'll also want to connect these things together. So, for example, in a table of posts, you'll want a field called `category_id` or something, with the row id of said category. Then you can easily link posts to categories, view all posts in a category, etc.

What is your understanding of connecting to a database, retrieving results, etc? If this is completely over your head, I would definitely advise getting a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book) like the other answer suggests.

Comment: I do understand you point, the site to remake doesn't matter as it is for practice only so digg is as good as any, but it seems somewhat simple (people post ads, although I never used the site myself so I could be wrong).

I'm guessing a web store would be too difficult to try and replicate :]

Comment: The best project to learn on is one you care about. Then you'll actually see it through to completion. So, do you and your friends like to share recipes? Maybe you're a photographer and want to create a photo-rating system? Maybe there's a site with data you like, but you hate the layout? Look at the web, look at what you do in life, and thing "how can i make this better/more efficient/prettier". go from there.

Comment: How about something like Kijiji? Would that be good practice?

Comment: Sure. Try something as simple as craigslist. (never used Kijiji before). I'll edit my answer to steps you should think about.

Comment: You have been helpful, moderators on this site however, have not been.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the best tools for learning PHP is the actual [documentation](http://php.net). It is probably the best documentation for any language out there.

You can also go for [books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book).